# Call to WriteHtml method produces TypeError while using mpdf with CodeIgniter4

Tags: php, codeigniter, pdf, typeerror, mpdf

I'm trying to use **mPDF** with **Codeigniter4**. When I call the function `$mpdf->WriteHtml($html)` after rendering the view and storing the result in $html variable, it throws an error at line $mpdf->WriteHtml($html). The error is

`TypeError Unsupported operand types: string * int`.

Pl. help resolve this.

I generated view without calling MPDF and it works fine. So there is no issue with the view.

Updated on Jan 02, 2023

I experimented further by removing all the HTML rendered and gradually adding elements. I am using MDBootstrap CSS using MSN (https://mdbootstrap.com/). I noted that as soon as I add "bg-secondary" to the class in one of the divs, the above error is thrown. There may be other such classes but this is the first one noted here.
PHP version is 8.1

```html
     <html>
     <head>
     <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font- 
     awesome/6.0.0/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
     <!-- Google Fonts -->
     <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css 
     family=Roboto:300,400,500,700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet"
     />
     <!-- MDB -->
     <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mdb-ui- 
     kit/6.0.1/mdb.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
     </head>
     <body>
    '<div class="container-md pt-2 border"  style="width: 80%">
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2 text-center">
    <img src="'.base_url().'/public/assets/images/MSAS_Logo.png" 
    class="img-fluid" width="70%" height="70%" alt="MSAS Logo" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-10 text-center">
    <p class="fs-3 lh-1">Meenakshi Sehkari Awaas Samiti</p>
    <p class="fs-6 lh-2">(Reg. No 1523. Plot No. 7, Sector PI,
    Greater Noida, (Distt. Gautam Budh Nagar), U.P - 201308.</p>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row bg-secondary"> 
    <div class="col-md-12 text-center justify-content-center" 
    <h3>Maintenance Bill Note</h3>
    </div>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: can you show the html code you are trying to save to pdf. What php version?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Do you use the last mPDF version? If the problem persists, share the stack trace of the error.